# Can nodemailer be used for free without major restrictions/limits?

Tags: email, html-email, nodemailer, invoice

I'm building an app where purchasing is involved and it needs to send a lot of emails. I've successfully set up nodemailer but don't understand if I can use that for free without limitations.
Missing an email could be crucial to the purpose of my web app. Is it not a good idea? thanks!

Comment: "Missing an email" -- but even if it was without limitations, you still may have general deliverability problems if you're DIYing. Sounds like this is for transactional email, so if it's crucial, be sure to tap into a server that has high reputation (crucial for email deliverability).

Comment: I'm sending this through gmail and it's host 'smtp.gmail.com' if that's what you mean. I've  never had problems with it in development, but obviously I can't send hundreds, of emails at the same time in development to test it so that's the problem. Do you have maybe any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think gmail is suitable for mass email. But if it's just for transactional email, it *might* be okay (haven't researched). There are limits e.g. 100 emails/ hour (again, off the top of my head, not researched). I've successfully used Postmark before, and you can also google for "Postmark alternatives" to find other similar providers.

Comment: I was thinking I could maybe slip away with using a free emailer service, but yeah I'm not surprised it would be better to use a paid one. Thanks for the info @Nathan!